# Showing a partially visible last line of an edit control?

Tags: c, user-interface, winapi

I'm noticing that standard edit controls are not showing the last line of text if it's not fully visible. Is there a way to override this behavior? If not, is there an equivalent solution to an edit box that does? Preferably in "pure" Win32 API fashion, as I am not using MFC or ATL. This is how I define the edit control at the moment:

```
CreateWindow(L"EDIT", NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_MULTILINE, 0, 0, 0, 0, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_EDIT_CONTROL, hInst, NULL);
```

Comment: That's just how the edit control works, I don't think there's a way to change it.